# Do std library `emplace` functions make use of `std::in_place` tag

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I want to know whether C++ standard library `emplace` functions make use of `std::in_place` tags (to indicate that the contained object should be constructed in-place)? Because `emplace` function got introduced in c++11 and `std::in_place` in c++17.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) it's only used for variant, optional and any

Comment: @AlanBirtles That looks like an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *entire point* of `emplace` and its ilk is to indicate that the object is being constructed in-place. The implementation isn't allowed to construct the item and copy/move it to its final location.

The main reason `in_place` is used in constructors is because constructors have to use overload resolution to tell which constructor you intend to call (for `any` and `variant`, they also specify the object type to construct as a template argument, since you can't provide template arguments to constructors outside of template argument deduction). So if you want to have something like the `push_back/emplace_back` distinction in a constructor, you have to do it with a parameter, not a function name.